# Using ajax with django framework to reload div and display json

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax

here is the web page I am currently working on: [web site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OHlG.png)

As you can see I have a config panel and what I would like to do is when I click on the 'Générer' button, the inverted tree appears and shows my configurations.

For this I use django with ajax: [ajax code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kjl3.png)

The url in the code send to this function in views.py: [compute function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41V7F.png)

And from the json which is created, I would like to use it in my html page like that for instance: [exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYs0Z.png)

Comment: Please don't put code in screenshots, instead paste it to the quesiton

Comment: Sorry I didn't know